# inheriting from MATLAB graphics objects

Tags: matlab, matlab-class

I need to create subclass of the Patch object's class in MATLAB 2014b but MATLAB does not allow me to do so:

`Class 'matlab.graphics.primitive.Patch' is Sealed and may not be used as a superclass.`

Is there a hack around this?

Answer (score 1):

No - you can't subclass a class that is `Sealed`, and `matlab.graphics.primitive.Patch` is a built-in class, so you can't make a (hack) edit to unseal it.

The best you can do is to use an Adapter pattern - create your own class, storing a `Patch` as a private (and maybe hidden) property, and then wrap all its properties and ones of your own, implementing `set` and `get` methods that pass through the value to/from the underlying `Patch`. Do something similar for any methods of `Patch` that you need. You may also need to listen to property change events on the `Patch` and respond to them appropriately.

Then you can add your own methods as well, and/or modify the existing method and property behavior as required.

Comment: Yeah, those ideas are some of the things I thought about at first. But I was wondering if there would be a (neat,) undocumented way to circumvent this limitation (e.g. via accessing the underlying `java` objects, etc). I have actually implemented what you have suggested actually, but like I said I was wondering whether there's a more general way to achieve the same result.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0):

No. If the class is sealed, it shall not be derived from. There are probably good reasons why it has been chosen to be sealed; other classes may assume a particular implementation which you can override if you were to inherit from the class.